# Why my code doesnt work in switch case?

Tags: c++

the code I wrote with file commands does not work in switch case , but it is working normally. What is the problem?

**Here my codes;**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int menu;
    FILE *files;
    char info[150];

    cout<< " \n ** MENU ** \n";
    cout<< "\n 1- Create File";
    cout<< "\n 2- Copy File";
    cout<< "\n 3- Copy without spaces";
    cout<< "\n 4- Merge Files";
    cout<< "\n 5- Quit \n";

    cout<< "\n Please Select : ";
    cin>>menu;

    switch (menu) {

    case 1:
        files = fopen("example.txt","w");
        printf("\n Information :"); gets(info);
        fprintf(files, info);
        fclose(files);
        break;
    default: "\n error";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include your desired behavior and the actual behavior in your question, as well as point out how it's going wrong. See [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean when you wrote "normally" ?

Comment: @GuillaumeFouillet
This section works normally, but when I add it to the switch case, the program does not work.






files = fopen(&quot;example.txt&quot;,&quot;w&quot;);
         
         printf(&quot;\n Information :&quot;); gets(info);
         
         fprintf(files, info);
         
        fclose(files);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put a getchar() in between `printf("\n Information :");` and `gets(info);`. like 
    `printf("\n Information :");
    getchar(); 
    gets(info);`
You are facing this problem for newline issue and how gets() handle previous entered newlines. Please read a more about `printf()`, `cin`,`cout`, `gets` about new line flashing. You will have a clear understanding.